# NET Framework 4.8 for ML.NET

Tags: c#

I wanted to use ML.NET and the Windows Forms "chart" within vs 2019.
Therefore, I created a new project with "Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)" and not "Windows Forms App" to use the target .NET Framework 4.8.
Although, I installed ML.NET Model Builder (Preview) under extensions, all classes show an error "The namespace "ML" does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft".

Is there maybe an installation issue or does ML.NET work with .NET 3.1 only (and not together with .NET Framework 4.8) ?

Answer (score 0):

restart your vs after that it should works fine.

Comment: The restart has not worked. Actually, the problem was the installation of ML.NET via "Extensions" in the main menu. It successfully worked by installing ML.NET via "Manage NuGet Packages" in the solution explorer.